# Unable to add ppas that contain '-'

Tags: 13.10, ppa

I have searched for this error and it seems I am the only one getting this problem. When I run, for example

```
    $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
    Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager'.
    Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

but when I add ppa's without any special characters, it runs fine. So, I can add webupd8team/gnome3, but when I try adding webupd8team/sublime-text-2, the same error shows. Does anybody know the reason and fix for this? I am using ubuntu 13.10
Thank you in advance.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to relate to recent updates to **Package "ca-certificates"**

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/saucy/main/proposed/ca-certificates

> .. Previously, the script would simply overwrite the first one found in the certdata.txt with the later one since they both have the same CKA_LABEL, resulting in identical filenames
>
> 1257265  --   ca-certificates not in sync with newer releases
>
> 1014640  --   12.04/openssl refusing some verisign certified sites

---

However, this has occurred before: (back on *February 10th, 2013*)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2113326&p=12502408#post12502408

```
Ok I found a fix for this problem and am posting it in case others have the same issue:

Note that
apt-get --reinstall install ca-certificates
and
dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
by themselves did not fix the issue.

However:
rm -rf /usr/share/ca-certificates
followed by
apt-get --reinstall install ca-certificates
```

Answer (score 2):

Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`

Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/fix-cannot-add-ppa-please-check-that.html

Comment: Already tried that. I'll include it in the question.

Comment: Did it again, and it worked! Is there any reason why this happens? Any way to prevent it?

Comment: @stranger_anon Not that I know of.